# Url rewrite from subdomain to domain

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a codeigniter webiste at my normal domain for example: `http://mywebsite.com`
And I have a sub domain like: `http://wordpress.mywebsite.com`.
Is it possible to rewrite the url from `http://wordpress.mywebsite.com/blog` to `http://mywebsite.com/blog`?

Kind regards

**Update**

This worked out for me:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^word.mywebsite.com/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com/blog$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

is it possible to rewrite one page ?